# inmobi javascript return empty banner

Tags: javascript, inmobi

I want to get a test ad banner from inmobi. According to inmobi Developer Wiki

http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=JavaScript

this script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inmobi_conf = {
        siteid : "4028cba631d63df10131e1d3191d00cb",
        slot : "15",
        test: "true"
    };
    </script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://cf.cdn.inmobi.com/ad/inmobi.js"></script>
```

must return test banner 320x50, but it always returns an empty banner.
Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting "No-Fill Response". From that link you provided:

> For example, if a publisher faces an NFR (No-Fill Response) scenario,
>   a callback is sent notifying that there is an NFR. The publisher can
>   now take steps to address and blank real estate issue that was caused
>   by non-availability of ads.

```
<div id="my-ad-slot">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var inmobi_conf = {
    siteid : "your site id",
    slot : "slot number",
    test: true,
    onError : function(code) {
        if(code == "nfr") {
            document.getElementById("my-ad-slot").style.display = "none";
            // do something else. call to other ad network or logic to display in-house ads, etc. 
        }
    }
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cf.cdn.inmobi.com/ad/inmobi.js"></script>
</div>
```

In the above code example, the parameter code will give nfr when no ads are returned.

Comment: If I understand correctly, from test site-id i don't response banner?

Comment: Exactly, it looks like no banners are currently being served to this site.

Comment: Thank you, 4028cba631d63df10131e1d3191d00cb - is inmobi test ID, I get her from http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=JavaScript.

Comment: Try it with your real ID when you get a chance (and probably it's a good idea to try it on a real site too, just a separate blank page). If you don't get ads even then - you may need to contact inmobi support. Keep in mind that on some ad networks ads don't appear right away, it may take some time.

Comment: @Vadym Did you resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Phill Healey No. With testing id it doesn't work. Try work with real ID and real site.

Comment: @Vadym I was trying both and no response. Hopefully by now my app/slot will have been authorised and I can try again with the relevant ID. Thanks for the update.